# How to perform CI with Xamarin UITest using Visual Studio

Tags: c#, ios, visual-studio, xamarin, continuous-integration

Ok, so my team is using Xamarin with Visual Studio and we trying to utilize UITest.

We want to include UITest as part of our CI, just like we do with our MSTests - but we are unsure what to do about iOS UITests. Because it's not possible to run UITest for iOS using Visual Studio, these tests will automatically fail/not run.

Our problem is that Visual Studio is the corporate standard and we're not supposed to use Xamarin Studio. It's fine to write the iOS UITests in Xamarin Studio, but our builds and CI is kicked off from Visual Studio. We are not using TestCloud, only UITest.

Does anyone have experience running Xamarin UITests as part of CI using Visual Studio/Windows? What do you do about the iOS tests? Do you just let them fail? Do you exclude them? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

At the moment, running iOS tests from Windows/Visual Studio is not possible. According to the [Xamarin documentation](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/testcloud/uitest/working-with/testing-on-devices/#Requirements):

> It is not possible to run UITests on iOS devices in Windows. You can only run UITests for iOS devices on Mac OS X.

This is because UITest relies on Instruments and other Xcode tools to launch and run iOS tests.

If you want to run your iOS tests from CI you will either need to run them from a Mac build host or upload them to Test Cloud.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. I was asking if people personally exclude the tests from visual studio or let them fail

Comment: @stepheaw So you have iOS tests that pass when running on a Mac, but you don't know what to do with them when running on Windows?